# Como llevo esta tabla generada en html a PDF

Tags: php, html2pdf

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en PHP y ya logre crear una tabla dinamica en html que se genera a traves de un arreglo y un foreach , ahora me requieren que esta tabla se debe generar en un archivo PDF, me dijeron que lo hiciera utilizando una librería que se llama html2pdf, realmente es muy sencillo, pero lo único que no se es como llevar esa tabla html al método que me genera el pdf.

A continuación dejo el codigo de tal cual como llevo el proyecto, para que me den una idea de como puedo ingresar esta tabla al método WriteHTML.

```php
$ArrayProyeccion = explode(chr(10),$_SESSION['Valor_Proyeccion']);

echo '<table id="infoGeneral" border="0" style="border:0px">';
echo '<tr class=odd><td style=width:50px>NO.<td>FECHA<td style=width:100px>VALOR CUOTA<td style=width:100px>INTERES<td style=width:100px>CAPITAL<td style=width:100px>ABONO EXTRA<td style=align:right;width:100px>NUEVO SALDO';

foreach ($ArrayProyeccion as $Linea){
  $ArrayLinea = explode('|', $Linea);
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $ArrayLinea[0];
  echo '<td>' . $ArrayLinea[5];
  $Interes = (float)str_replace(',','.',$ArrayLinea[6]);
  $Capital = (float)str_replace(',','.',$ArrayLinea[7]);
  $Abonoextra = (float)str_replace(',','.',$ArrayLinea[8]);
  $Cuota = $Interes + $Capital + $Abonoextra;
  $Nuevosaldo = (float)str_replace(',','.',$ArrayLinea[9]);

  if ($Cuota != 0)
    echo '<td style=text-align:right;>' . number_format($Cuota,2,'.',',');
  else
    echo '<td>';

  if ($Interes != 0)
    echo '<td style=text-align:right;>' . number_format($Interes,2,'.',',');
  else
    echo '<td>';

  if ($Capital != 0)
    echo '<td style=text-align:right;>' . number_format($Capital,2,'.',',');
  else
    echo '<td>';

  if ($Abonoextra != 0)
    echo '<td style=text-align:right;>' . number_format($Abonoextra,2,'.',',');
  else
    echo '<td>';

  if ($Nuevosaldo != 0)
    echo '<td style=text-align:right>' . number_format($Nuevosaldo,2,'.',',');
  else
    echo '<td>';            

  $AcumInteres = $AcumInteres + $Interes;
  $AcumCapital = $AcumCapital + $Capital;
  $AcumAbonoextra = $AcumAbonoextra + $Abonoextra;
}

echo '<tr class=odd><td colspan=3>TOTAL';
echo '<td style=text-align:right>' . number_format($AcumInteres,2,'.',',');
echo '<td style=text-align:right>' . number_format($AcumCapital,2,'.',',');
echo '<td style=text-align:right>' . number_format($AcumAbonoextra,2,'.',',');
echo '<td></table>';

//echo $ArrayProyeccion ;

ob_end_clean();

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetProtection(array('print'), '');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($ArrayLinea);
$html2pdf->Output('Certificado.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es una variable de tipo `string` y donde estas haciendo todos los `echo` guardas esas lineas en la variable, para que al final se la pases a la función `WriteHTML` de la `librería` y obvio antes de eso haces solo un `echo` a la variable

Comment: te sugiero revisar este tutorial muy completo : https://huguidugui.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/pdf-desde-php-html2pdf-15/